# Reactive API consumes external api

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm building an API that consumes another external service's API and maps the response.
Using WebClient to make an HTTP request.
External API is not non-blocking.

I'm going to block `fetchResult` instead of returning `Mono<ResultObject>` as a response because I'm not sure if returning Mono response makes sense in case of external service is blocking.

So my question is If an external API is not non-blocking, does return a non-blocking response lose its meaning?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: external api doesn't matter, it's the same http call whether the target is blocking or not

Answer (score 1):

It is irrelevant if the external API is blocking or non-blocking, HTTP protocol will be always in the middle. What you should definitely do is use `Mono` and `Flux` throughout your service. An important thing is that if you are using a database, it should also support the reactive stack so that you can take full advantage of using Spring Webflux.